# Special path to files with fine-upload

Tags: fine-uploader

I want to transfer files in different folders on the server.
I did not find an option in the documentation to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't worked with fine-uploader before but it appears to just be a front-end/client-side library and the server-side code handles the uploading. What have you done so far on the server-side code?

Comment: Hi, Please provide more details e.g. fine uploader server side is in php, node.js and java etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using php endpoint, you can user php `rename` function as following after the file is uploaded.

```
rename("user/image1.jpg", "user/del/image1.jpg");
```